# Proper use of Wildcard in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I have to use a makefile in order to copy all the contents of say Folder 1 into Folder 2. The contents of folder 1 are 5 files having names as abc_1.c,abc_2.c,.. and so on.
The paths of folders 1 & 2 are both given as variables in makefile and then the command for copy is being given. 
The problem is that even after using Wildcard function I am able to copy the entire folder 1 into folder 2, and not the contents of folder1. 
Kindly help me out by suggesting a method to copy the contents of folder 1 into 2 and not the entire folder.

Following is the code snippet which I used initially :
`PATH_1 = /ace/1/*`
`PATH_2 = /ace/2/`
The code to copy : `shell cp -rf ("$(PATH_1)") ("$(PATH_2)")`
Pls dont mind the above line of code.

The main problem was in PATH_1 as the '*' was not resolved properly and the contents were not copied. On removing the '*' from PATH_1 the code worked but again it copied entire folder 1 into folder 2.

Later, I modified Path_1 as follows :
`PATH_1 = /ace/1/(wildcard abc_*.c)`

Still the same thing, the entire folder 1 is being copied into folder 2.
Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: What version of make are you using? (Try typing `make -v`.) The snippet above is not a working makefile rule. With slight modifications it works perfectly. What is your rule?

Comment: `"$(PATH_1)"` prevents expansion of `*` by the shell because of the double-quotes. `$(PATH_1)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something on these lines:

```
PATH1=/ace/1
PATH2=/ace/2
C_SRCS=$(wildcard $(PATH1)/abc_*.c)

copy:
     cp -vi ${C_SRCS} $(PATH2)
```

The copy options `v` is for verbose & `i` is for interactive, which you can ignore if you want to.
This rule will fail with error with `C_SRCS` is empty, to prevent that you can have a slightly robust rule something on these lines:

```
copy:
     for C_SRC in ${C_SRCS}; do \
         cp -vi $$C_SRC $(PATH2);  \
     done
```

Hope this helps!